# Android and crowdsourcing

Tags: android

I'm thinking about putting an half-developed app idea up on Indie GoGo (worldwide variant of Kickstarter) but am considering how to handle delivery.

I need to make sure that just the right people can get the app they pledge for, do you know if there's a way to bind certain users to an app so only they can download it? I was thinking of using the e-mail of their Google account since they need one anyway.

I would then upload the same app publicly for a higher price for everybody else once it's done. If this way isn't supported, do you know how other people have solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will be hard to do. But I have some ideas that you can use:

1. First of all if you have emails of your subscribers then you can directly send them your app.
2. If you want to place your application on Google Play then it's more difficult. I hope the following approach can be used. You can create a stub for your application. This stub during the run will check if a user possesses with some purchased item. If he possess then you simply start your application (inside your application you can also put this type of checks to be more difficult to crack your application). If the user does not have this item you propose him to buy it. During this you check if the user is in your list. If he is then you select one price if not then another.

These are just my thoughts. I've never implemented something similar.

Comment: Both suggestions are not safe. Users could simply copy the apk into their phones via USB, for example.